# Change the texture of an existing model in google model-viewer using an image file

Tags: javascript, 3d, texture-mapping, gltf, model-viewer

I am a student with an upcoming project using Google's model-viewer to render a poster using AR on a user's wall. I have a simple, textureless, one-sided plane that I made using the three.js online editor, which lives in my project's directory. I am trying to implement a system where the texture of that plane can be set to an image to simulate a poster/painting/etc.

Google's [model-viewer documentation](https://modelviewer.dev/examples/scenegraph/) has an example (the one with the rubber duck) in which a model has a texture created and set from a referenced image file, and I have attempted to implement it on my end using the plane and various images of different types in place of their examples, but I cannot get it to work.

I have been looking for possible solutions online for a long time with no real progress so I figured it was time to ask the question for myself. The documentation makes this look simple enough so clearly, I'm misunderstanding something.

Here is the modified code from the model-viewer documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Model-Viewer Test</title>
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    model-viewer {
      width: 400px;
      height: 600px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <model-viewer id="plane" camera-controls src="assets/blank.glb" ar ar-modes="webxr">
    <div class="controls">
      <p>Textures</p>
      <select id="normals2">
        <option>None</option>
        <option value="assets/planet.jpeg">Forbidden Planet</option>
        <option value="assets/retro.jpg">Retro Camera</option>
        <option value="assets/movie.png">Movie Poster</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </model-viewer>
  <script type="module">
    const modelViewerTexture = document.querySelector("model-viewer#plane");

    modelViewerTexture.addEventListener("load", () => {

      const material = modelViewerTexture.model.materials[0];

      const createAndApplyTexture = async (channel, event) => {

        if (event.target.value == "None") {
          // Clears the texture.
          material[channel].setTexture(null);
        } else if (event.target.value) {
          // Creates a new texture.
          const texture = await modelViewerTexture.createTexture(event.target.value);
          // Set the texture name
          texture.name = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase();
          // Applies the new texture to the specified channel.
          material[channel].setTexture(texture);
        }
      }

      document.querySelector('#normals2').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
        createAndApplyTexture('normalTexture', event);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The only response I get when picking an option in the selector is the error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property name of #<xy> which has only a getter
    at createAndApplyTexture
```

which refers to line 46:

```
texture.name = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase();
```

and otherwise, nothing happens. The plane itself is rendering with no problems. I have tried using both a .gltf and a .glb model.

I do not intend to plagiarize from Google's documentation on the actual project as I have done here, I just wanted to see if I could get the dynamic textures working beforehand and immediately hit a wall.

Thank you to anyone who sees or responds to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late for your school project, but I had similar headaches with texture swapping for a long time.  I also happen to be a student :D.  Here's an example which I wrote: https://pastebin.com/d0enJ11Z.  I'm using a drop down list to select materials, but if that is not needed, you can simplify the code even further.
The most important bit of code is this right here.

```
const material = speaker.model.materials[0];

//Get current text value (name) of selected option
var e = document.getElementById("color-controls");
var finishName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
material.pbrMetallicRoughness['baseColorTexture'].texture.source.setURI(e.value);
```

I'm not sure if `finishName` does anything but I'm too scared to remove it and break everything.  Theoretically, all you need is

```
const material = speaker.model.materials[0];
material.pbrMetallicRoughness['baseColorTexture'].texture.source.setURI("https://thereisatexturefilehere.com");
```

This will select the first material in the material index, and then set the texture of that index in the baseColorTexture channel.  I hope this was helpful!

P.S. it's setURI, not setURL